# How do I tell if a bag of concrete is OK?

Tags: concrete

We have a number of bags of pre-mixed concrete (Quikrete) around the shop that have been sitting around for awhile.  Most are sealed but a few have been opened.   All feel like a solid rock, not like a bag of sand.

if they're no good, I'd like to throw them out now.   If they are good, I'd like to store them indefinitely for a future project.

How do I tell the difference without opening them?

Answer (score 4):

Without opening...lift them, they should have some squeeze/give and feel soft. Hard as a rock, then most likely not good.

Comment: Or hit it (somewhat gently) with a hammer/mallet.  You should be able to tell if its rock hard.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, any cement, concrete, or mortar, mix should be tossed after 2 years, max, even if unopened; 1 year if you live in a high-humidity area, such as Florida. Placing an opened remainder bag into two plastic bags MAY extend those times, but don't count on it. The bags are cheap enough that you should buy only what you need, and dispose of the rest, properly. The only way to ensure "indefinite" usage is to place the bag - - opened or not - - into a vacuum-sealed, low-humidity (under 30%) area! (n.b., most safes are not humidity proof)

Answer (score 2):

If it feels like a solid rock, it has gotten wet and set up inside the bag. Trash em.